# Custom object array binding?

Tags: handsontable

I've looked through the documentation, but perhaps I've overlooked what I assume to be a straightforward task. Is it possible to provide a custom binding function so that, in an array of objects, each object corresponds to one cell, rather than each object corresponding to a full row? Would this binding maintain the reference to the original object so that the data would change after being modified in the spreadsheet?

For example, I'd want to create the following sheet:

[image: Example spreadsheet]

With JSON in this structure:

```
[
    {
        "name": "USA",
        "year": 2015,
        "sales": 1,
    },
    {
        "name": "USA",
        "year": 2016,
        "sales": 2,
    },
    {
        "name": "USA",
        "year": 2017,
        "sales": 3,
    },
    {
        "name": "Canada",
        "year": 2015,
        "sales": 4,
    },
    {
        "name": "Canada",
        "year": 2016,
        "sales": 5,
    },
    {
        "name": "Canada",
        "year": 2017,
        "sales": 6,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `columns` definition. In there you can define the data source for each column such that it will iterate through your objects and set the values of each column given the id for that column. And yes, it uses references so if you edit them, your objects get edited as well.

Comment: I've read both http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/Options.html#columns and http://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html?_ga=1.19807611.2130437994.1441283583, but I don't see any similar examples. For instance, if I specify the `columns` definition as `columns: [{data: "name"}, {data: "sales"}`, I'll get a row for each object, whereas I want a cell for each object instead due to the structure of my JSON data source. Is there a `columns` option function for doing so?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `cells` instead of `columns`. Same idea but you specify it for each cell using `row` and `col` indeces.

Comment: Look at the last example here: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/demo-read-only.html